# How to manage through put of Azure Table Storage? (like AWS)

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

AWS dynamo db has a throughput parameter you can set.

How does Azure Table Storage scale in that regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Azure Table Storage does not provide a throughput parameter instead with throughput is already set for the Azure Table storage as described in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/05/10/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets.aspx).

Single Table Partition – a table partition are all of the entities in a table with the same partition key value, and most tables have many partitions. The throughput target for a single partition is:

- Up to 500 entities per second
- Note, this is for a single partition, and not a single table. Therefore, a table with good partitioning, can process up to a few thousand requests per second (up to the storage account target).